# Why is goroutine starving?

Tags: go

My client is fairly simple. There are two goroutines as well:

1. The main goroutine: Just "for" loop, but with calling function.
2. The second goroutine: This goroutine just panic.

```golang
package main

import (
    "runtime"
)

func main() {
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(1)
    go func() {
        panic(1)
    }()
    for {
        Test()
    }
}

func Test() {
    _ = make([]byte, 200)
    a := 1
    for {
        a++
        if a == 10 {
            break
        }
    }
}
```

My golang version is go1.14.3.

There is function call which do not get inlined and is not small in the main goroutine, so main goroutine should be preempted by sysmon. second goroutine will get chance to execute, and panic.

But nothing happened. Please help!

```sh
GODEBUG=asyncpreemptoff=1 go run main.go
```

Comment: From the docs: «asyncpreemptoff=1 disables signal-based asynchronous goroutine preemption. This makes some loops non-preemptible for long periods». So you've switched the preemption off and observe the `for` loop chugging away giving the goroutine which should panic no chance to run, right?

Comment: I think function call in "for" loop can trigger “morestack”，then trigger preemption.

Comment: But why should it? Whatever the `Test` function allocates is discarded as soon as it exits. Also, since the allocation is assigned to a variable which is not used I'm pretty sure the compiled might have elided the allocation right away (not to mention the fact it's free to allocate reasonably small-ish pieces of memory on the stack if it can prove the pointer to that memory won't escape (the case with your code).

Comment: Another case which might occur is that the compiled inlined the call to `Test` right into the `for` loop's body. (You could do `go build -gcflags=-m ...`)

Comment: I edited my question. thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I must start with a remark that this question is really not fit for SO as it implied some sort of a discussion — which had already happened in the comments to the original version of the question, — and should better had been asked on [the mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/golang-nuts) instead.

But OK, let's try to address v2 of your question which contains the following code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "runtime"
)

func main() {
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(1)
    go func() {
        panic(1)
    }()
    for {
        Test()
    }
}

func Test() {
    _ = make([]byte, 200)
    a := 1
    for {
        a++
        if a == 10 {
            break
        }
    }
}
```

If we ask the compiler to dump the assembly code it generated for your program — by running

```
go build -gcflags=-S preempt.go 2>preempt.S
```

(the dump goes to `stderr`, so that's why `2>...`), on `linux/amd64` and Go 1.14.3, we'll get (elided):

```
# command-line-arguments
"".main STEXT size=80 args=0x0 locals=0x18
    0x0000 00000 (preempt.go:7) TEXT    "".main(SB), ABIInternal, $24-0
    0x0000 00000 (preempt.go:7) MOVQ    (TLS), CX
    0x0009 00009 (preempt.go:7) CMPQ    SP, 16(CX)
    0x000d 00013 (preempt.go:7) JLS 73
    0x000f 00015 (preempt.go:7) SUBQ    $24, SP
    0x0013 00019 (preempt.go:7) MOVQ    BP, 16(SP)
    0x0018 00024 (preempt.go:7) LEAQ    16(SP), BP
    0x001d 00029 (preempt.go:7) FUNCDATA    $0, gclocals·33cdeccccebe80329f1fdbee7f5874cb(SB)
    0x001d 00029 (preempt.go:7) FUNCDATA    $1, gclocals·33cdeccccebe80329f1fdbee7f5874cb(SB)
    0x001d 00029 (preempt.go:7) FUNCDATA    $2, gclocals·9fb7f0986f647f17cb53dda1484e0f7a(SB)
    0x001d 00029 (preempt.go:8) PCDATA  $0, $0
    0x001d 00029 (preempt.go:8) PCDATA  $1, $0
    0x001d 00029 (preempt.go:8) MOVQ    $1, (SP)
    0x0025 00037 (preempt.go:8) CALL    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(SB)
    0x002a 00042 (preempt.go:9) MOVL    $0, (SP)
    0x0031 00049 (preempt.go:9) PCDATA  $0, $1
    0x0031 00049 (preempt.go:9) LEAQ    "".main.func1·f(SB), AX
    0x0038 00056 (preempt.go:9) PCDATA  $0, $0
    0x0038 00056 (preempt.go:9) MOVQ    AX, 8(SP)
    0x003d 00061 (preempt.go:9) CALL    runtime.newproc(SB)
    0x0042 00066 (preempt.go:13)    CALL    "".Test(SB)
    0x0047 00071 (preempt.go:13)    JMP 66
    0x0049 00073 (preempt.go:13)    NOP
    0x0049 00073 (preempt.go:7) PCDATA  $1, $-1
    0x0049 00073 (preempt.go:7) PCDATA  $0, $-1
    0x0049 00073 (preempt.go:7) CALL    runtime.morestack_noctxt(SB)
    0x004e 00078 (preempt.go:7) JMP 0
<…>
"".Test STEXT nosplit size=17 args=0x0 locals=0x0
    0x0000 00000 (preempt.go:17)    TEXT    "".Test(SB), NOSPLIT|ABIInternal, $0-0
    0x0000 00000 (preempt.go:17)    FUNCDATA    $0, gclocals·33cdeccccebe80329f1fdbee7f5874cb(SB)
    0x0000 00000 (preempt.go:17)    FUNCDATA    $1, gclocals·33cdeccccebe80329f1fdbee7f5874cb(SB)
    0x0000 00000 (preempt.go:17)    FUNCDATA    $2, gclocals·33cdeccccebe80329f1fdbee7f5874cb(SB)
    0x0000 00000 (preempt.go:17)    PCDATA  $0, $0
    0x0000 00000 (preempt.go:17)    PCDATA  $1, $0
    0x0000 00000 (preempt.go:17)    MOVL    $1, AX
    0x0005 00005 (preempt.go:20)    JMP 10
    0x0007 00007 (preempt.go:21)    INCQ    AX
    0x000a 00010 (preempt.go:22)    CMPQ    AX, $9
    0x000e 00014 (preempt.go:22)    JNE 7
    0x0010 00016 (<unknown line number>)    PCDATA  $0, $-2
    0x0010 00016 (<unknown line number>)    PCDATA  $1, $-2
    0x0010 00016 (<unknown line number>)    RET
<…>
```

Here the listing starts with the body of `main` and then continues with the body of `Test`.

In `main`, of the most interest is the following bit:

```
    0x0042 00066 (preempt.go:13)    CALL    "".Test(SB)
    0x0047 00071 (preempt.go:13)    JMP 66
```

This is basically your `for` loop turned into a `CALL` to the `Test` function followed by an unconditional `JMP` to the `CALL`'s address.

As you can see, no code for anything to assist in preemption in sight yet.

Let's now look at the `Test`'s code.

The first thing to note is that there's no traces of the slice allocation in sight: it was optimized away.

But let's now look at the somewhat cryptic declaration of the function which reads:

```
0x0000 00000 (preempt.go:17)    TEXT    "".Test(SB), NOSPLIT|ABIInternal, $0-0
```

Of the most interest is that `NOSPLIT` bit.
If we consult [the docs on the Go's assembler](https://golang.org/doc/asm), we'll find that

> For example, here is a simple complete function definition.
>   The `TEXT` directive declares the symbol <…>
>   and the instructions that follow form the body of the function.
>
> <…>
>
> - `NOSPLIT = 4`
>     (For `TEXT` items.) Don't insert the preamble to check if the stack must be split. The frame for the routine, plus anything it calls, must fit in the spare space at the top of the stack segment. Used to protect routines such as the stack splitting code itself.

It can be hard to understand why exactly it's called this way and mentions "splitting" but that's from the days when Go's goroutines had "split stacks": that is, when the goroutine's stack had to grow, and had no free room in it, another "chunk" would have been allocated for it, and linked to the original; the process could repeat several times — resulting in a multi-segmented, split, stacks. Hence the name.
Later in the Go's development cycle [goroutine stacks became contiguous and reallocatable](https://golang.org/doc/go1.4#introduction) (much like backing arrays of slices), but the name of this obscure identifier was kept for backwards compatibility.

OK, so the thing is: the compiler noticed the function `Test` does not allocate anything on its stack, so it never ever uses any stack space beyond its own stack frame (which is allocated by the caller) and so the compiler went on and marked the function as `NOSPLIT` to eliminate any runtime checks for the need to grow the stack — to gain call speedup.

And that's what you observe at runtime.

---

In case it's of interest to you, you can disassemble an already built executable image by running `go tool objdump` on it.
It's also reasonably fine for analysis but contains lots of cruft as all the runtime, stdlib and initialization code which got linked in is disassembled along with your own code, which you need to search for in the dump.

Comment: Beautiful answer.